# Regex - matching text after the nth '\n'

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping

I have a sample text like this:

```
"\n                                                                                    Apr 15, 2019\n                                                                                12:00 PM – 3:00 PMWMC 2502, Burnaby\n                                        "
```

I want to extract the date, time and location separately.

What I am thinking is to extract whatever before the second "\n", this should gives me "\n           Apr 15, 2019". Then I can remove the "\n" and white spaces.
Then for the time, I want to remove whatever before the second "\n" and whatever after "PM".
For the location, just keep whatever after PM, then remove the "\n" and white spaces.

Here is the result I want:

```
[1] Apr 15, 2019
[2] 12:00 PM – 3:00 PM
[3] WMC 2502, Burnaby
```

Could anyone tell me how to do this? Doing it in some other ways is fine too.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you added your sample text correctly. EDIT: Nevermind. Didn't realize it was all on one line and there was horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Try `strsplit(INPUT, "\\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R one-liner using `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(ss, "(\\s{2,}|(?<=[AP]M)(?=\\w))", perl = T), function(x) x[x != ""])    #     [,1]
#[1,] "Apr 15, 2019"
#[2,] "12:00 PM – 3:00 PM"
#[3,] "WMC 2502, Burnaby"
```

It's difficult to say how well this generalises on account of the very small sample string.

Explanation: We split `ss` on *either* a stretch of at least 2 whitespaces `"\\s{2,}"` (this avoids splitting on a single whitespace), *or* at a position that is preceded by `"[AP]M"` through a positive look-behind and followed by a word character (i.e. not a whitespace) through a positive look-ahead `"(?<=[AP]M)(?=\\w)"`.

---

### Sample data

```
ss <- "\n                                                                                    Apr 15, 2019\n                                                                                12:00 PM – 3:00 PMWMC 2502, Burnaby\n                                        "
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your strings share the same structure with the sample text.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

str_split(x, "\\n", simplify = T) %>%
  trimws() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(
    time = str_match(V3, "^.+PM"),
    location = gsub(time, "", V3)
  ) %>%
  select(
    date = 2,
    time,
    location
  )

#           date               time          location
# 1 Apr 15, 2019 12:00 PM – 3:00 PM WMC 2502, Burnaby
```